# Does 'sudo apt-get purge postgr*' remove database files?

Tags: apt, data-recovery, postgresql, database

I ran `sudo -u postgres psql -c "show data_directory"` and it shows `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main`. If I understand correctly, this is the directory that stores the database files.

I ran `sudo apt-get purge postgr*`. Did this remove the database files?
Running `sudo apt-file list postgresql` did not show `/var/lib/postgresql` in its entries, which means it shouldn't have purged those files, right?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm not exactly sure what data there was in the database and running `ls -l /var/lib/postgresql` is showing "time modified" around the time that I purged postgresql on all files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Debian packages of PostgreSQL before version 11 delete clusters when the server package is removed; so purging `postgresql-9.5` in your case would have deleted the database. (See [the `posgresql-9.6` `postrm`](https://sources.debian.org/src/postgresql-9.6/9.6.13-0+deb9u1/debian/postgresql-9.6.postrm/) for the gory details.)

You’re not the first person to be surprised by this; [bug #911940](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=911940) requested that the data be left alone, and PostgreSQL 11 in Debian 10 will ask the user before deleting the databases.

(`apt-file list` or `dpkg -L` aren’t reliable indicators of what will be purged; purging can involve maintainer scripts which can delete other files.)

Comment: well, this sucks